# `IORegisterForSystemPower failed` in file dialogs

Tags: macos

I have a very simple Qt program that just opens a file dialog. For some reason in some cases I get a spinning beach ball for about 5 seconds before the dialog opens, and it prints `IORegisterForSystemPower failed` to the console.

I have also noticed similar delays before file dialogs in other programs, like LyX and even Chrome.

I'm on OSX 10.12.3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just worked out a cause, sort of. If I open *two* instances of the program, then open the dialog in the first one it is instant. If I leave it open and try to open it in the second instance I get the beach ball.

If I just have two instances of the program running then it is instance, it's only when I try to open a second file dialog that it breaks.

I'd say it was a Qt bug but since it happens in Chrome too I'm going with an OSX bug.